# how to deploy in debug mode a symfony2 app with capifony?

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, capistrano, capifony

I have deployed my application on my website and it works finally just fine.
However, I've made a second deployment with the multistage option of capifony, this one is called development as opposed to production.

Inside my development.rb file, I have set :

> set :clear_controllers, false

so that the file app_dev.php does not get removed. Indeed it is available but it does not launch by default despite the following virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.sebastienvassaux.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/development/current/web

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/development/current/web
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/development/current/web>
        DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So first question: how do I do for the mysite.com to load app_dev.php and not app.php ?

Then, if I manually enter the address mysite.com/app_dev.php, I get the following error :

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 42: Attempted to load
>   class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace
>   "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   another namespace?

Well, this error is not raised when I work locally in dev mode, why is it raised here? What can I do to further understand the issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that composer has a section require-dev that is not gathered or added to the autoloader.

You can configure capifony to include the require-dev, prefrabily in you development.rb:

```
set :composer_options,  "--dev --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress"
```

In conjuntion with `set :clear_controllers, false` you should be able to run app_dev.php

Hope that it helps

Comment: Nice, it works fine now when I put app_dev.php manually. But still, the root url does not directly load app_dev but just app, depsite my virtualhost config. Any idea of what I could do to change this ?